# Flutter: Можно ли проверить, отрисован ли виджет

Tags: flutter

Мне необходимо вызвать метод после отрисовки виджета, иначе я получу ошибку.
Поэтому я хочу знать, есть ли какой-либо способ проверить статус виджета, может быть listener, который поможет с этим?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ @Spatz хороший, также рекомендую почитать: [как работает рендер в Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/rendering). Но если вы планируете использовать такой трюк многократно, то лучше использовать плагин [after_layout](https://pub.dev/packages/after_layout) который делает все намного удобнее. Пример:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:after_layout/after_layout.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomeScreenState createState() => new HomeScreenState();
}

class HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> with AfterLayoutMixin<HomeScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Рисуем виджет как обычно.
    return new Scaffold(body: new Container(color: Colors.red));
  }

  @override
  void afterFirstLayout(BuildContext context) {
    // Здесь уже виджет отрисован.
    return new showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
            content: new Text('Hello World'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              new FlatButton(
                child: new Text('DISMISS'),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              )
            ],
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать метод [addPostFrameCallback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html), который регистрирует колбэк вызываемый по завершении очередного "кадра" отрисовки.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => onAfterBuild(context));

  return Container(
    ...
  );
}

void _onAfterBuild(BuildContext context){
  // здесь уже виджет отрисован
}
```

[Небольшая статейка на английском](https://www.didierboelens.com/faq/week2/)

Comment: Я думаю можно было привести оба варианта, в зависимости от задачи автор выбрал подходящие.